# how do you select all siblings which are generated dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code works when I have an element (generated dynamically) and I want to select the sibling of that element just once.

how would I select the sibling off all instances of that same class (no idea to know how many since they are generated dynamically). in this case that class is ".username"

```
  $('#chats').on("click", ".username", function(e){
    $(this).next().css("font-weight", "bold");

  })
```

visually, I have a ".username" div which will contain as a sibling a p element.

Comment: Do you want to do it on click (one div clicked -> all paragraphs get bold?), or when elements are loaded/generated?

Comment: when one div clicked, all present and future respective paragraphs bolded!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q87er15q/ like this?

Comment: almost! that selects elements currently on the page, but when it fetches chats from the server (from the same user) and new ones appear on the page, those messages aren't bolded :)

Comment: So call the function that bold the initial elements after the new ones are fetched.